# PHP-MVC : instantiate Controllers in Core

Tags: php, autoloader

I am actually learning the MVC pattern but since 2 days i can't resolve the following problem :

I have a Core\Core() class in which i want to instantiate src\Controller\Controller() classes depending on route.

I created an autoloader that seems to work:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($class){

$base_dir = dirname(__DIR__);
$file = $base_dir . '/' . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class). '.php';

if(is_readable($file)){
    require_once $base_dir . '/' . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class . '.php');
}
});
```

I have the autoloader required on index.php and I am calling my Core\Core() in index.php but it doesn't load my Controller clesses.

I have this message :

Uncaught Error: Class 'AppController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PiePHP\Core\Core.php:22

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add code of index.php file too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved : I needed to set namespace like this :

```
$class = 'src\\Controller\\' . self::$currentController;
   $controller = new $class();
   $method = self::$currentMethod;
   $controller->$method();
```